# Is there a way to force-close a port on which a process is listening outside of killing the process directly?

Tags: .net, http, httplistener

It is understood that closing a port on which a process is listening will potentially render the process useless, so it is probably better to kill the process. However, I have a scenario where the process hangs when it tries to close the port. Nothing can then terminate the process except for a reboot of the server.  The stack trace from the memory dump is:

```
0012f230 7c82845c [NDirectMethodFrameStandalone: 0012f230] System.Net.UnsafeNclNativeMethods+SafeNetHandles.CloseHandle(IntPtr)
0012f240 7a567a78 System.Net.SafeCloseHandle.ReleaseHandle()
0012f24c 7928faa2 System.Runtime.InteropServices.CriticalHandle.Cleanup()
0012f25c 7928fa45 System.Runtime.InteropServices.CriticalHandle.Dispose(Boolean)
0012f260 7a59d907 System.Net.HttpListener.Stop()
```

Killing the process directly without attempting this graceful shut-down does not seem to work any better (same result -- the process hangs and cannot be terminated).

The question is: **Is there a way to force-close the port in this scenario from outside of the process?**

Everything I've read indicates that the best way to close a port is to kill the process listening on it but that's obviously doesn't work in my case.